# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AsyncPagedListDiffer cannot handle both contiguous and non-contiguous lists

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I'm using android jetpack paging library. and I have the following observer on my MVVM.
observer = new Observer<PagedList>() {

```
        @Override
        public void onChanged(PagedList<Problem> problems) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: adapter size = " + problems.size());

            adapter.submitList(problems);
        }

    };
```

now I'm retrieving some data from the database and I want to submit a List to the adapter.
I did some research and found a way of converting a List of Object to a PagedList.
The problem is that whenever I try to submit a new list I get the following Error message :
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AsyncPagedListDiffer cannot handle both contiguous and non-contiguous lists**.
so, is there's any way that I could change my PagedList into a Conteguos PagedList ? I think the answer is to make my PagedList a PagedList with a single Page. any help please?.

Answer (score 1):

In Paging2, a `PagedList` is either contiguous or tiled, to handle cases where a user may scroll far into placeholders and instead of loading many pages adjacently, you want to be able to "jump" to that position and resume loading from there.

So in order for a `PagedList` to be tiled, it must both:

1. Come from a `DataSource` which overrides:

```
@Override
boolean isContiguous() {
    return false;
}
```

2. Placeholders must be enabled via `PagedList.Config.enablePlaceholders` as doing so basically opts you into tiling behavior (if it is supported).

The error you're seeing is basically a warning that you're trying to support the fast-scroll / jumping case, but using a `DataSource` which only supports loading adjacent pages.

If you haven't checked it out yet, I would recommend trying out Paging3, as it does away with the entire tiling thing and generalizes the concept of jumps to all types of `DataSource`s by generalizing them to a single `PagingSource` type that explicitly opts in and defines jumping behavior.

Also, since you hinted that you're fetching data from DB to submit as a static list - the common way to do this via something like Room or SqlDelite would be to use their built-in Paging support to generate a DataSource.Factory implementation directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm taking everything one after anther so, I was wondering which DataSource I can find the function isContiguos() in? I'm kinda a beginner with android.
also it will be very helpful if you can give me a tutorial for migrating to paging3 as the official documentation is not very clear.

Comment: `isContiguous` is an internal method, it is set explicitly for DataSource types that do not support tiling. So anything that extends `PositionalDataSource`, such as implementation generated by room will support tiling. The error is warning about mixing results from a contiguous source with a tiled source.

Comment: I would recommend to go with Paging3 if you are just started out. Asking for my own benefit so that I can improve the docs - which parts of the documentation do you find unclear?

Comment: In addition to the documentation on DAC, also check out this sample here: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingSample